# My Hello World program on VS Code(C++) is not running (#include errors)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I have started learning C++ and am using VS Code and MinGW. I have installed the Microsoft C/C++ Extension.

I tried Hello World code but the following error is shown.

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (D:\CODE\C++\HelloWorld).

cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h" (dependency of "iostream")
```

The Code I wrote is

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

My c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
            "C:/Users/Hp/Downloads/dlib-19.21.0/dlib-19.21.0/dlib/bits"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

I have seen similar problems on the internet and tried solving it but wasnt able to do so.
It is the first time i have ever used VS Code and am not familiar with things.

Comment: You need to add another folder to your `includePath`. Open `C:\MinGW` with file explorer and search for `c++config.h`.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But now it says    cannot open source file "bits/c++locale.h" (dependency of "iostream")     i tried to add this folder too but i cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: These two files (c++config.h and c++locale.h) should be in the same folder. You may have a corrupt mingw installation. It's too old anyway. I recommend removing it and getting a fresh mingw install from https://www.msys2.org/.

Comment: Oh its done now i had to save the with .cpp extension which i didnt do.